# parent keys not found Oracle 10g

Tags: oracle

I have two tables :

```
SQL> desc SEGMENT
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 INDIP                                     NOT NULL VARCHAR2(11)
 NOMSEGMENT                                NOT NULL VARCHAR2(20)
 ETAGE  

SQL> desc POSTE
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 NPOSTE                                    NOT NULL VARCHAR2(7)
 NOMPOSTE                                  NOT NULL VARCHAR2(20)
 INDIP                                              VARCHAR2(11)
 AD                                                 VARCHAR2(3)
 TYPEPOSTE                                          VARCHAR2(9)
 NSALLE                                             VARCHAR2(7)
```

I want to add a constraint as the following :

```
 ALTER TABLE "POSTE" ADD CONSTRAINT "FK_POSTE_SEGMENT" FOREIGN KEY ("INDIP") REFERENCES "SEGMENT" ("INDIP") ENABLE;
```

But I got this error message :

> ERROR at line 1: ORA-02298: cannot validate (AIMAD.FK_POSTE_SEGMENT) -
>   parent keys not found

How can I solve this

Answer (score 0):

You should check what POSTE table does not contain values in INDIP column what don't exist in INDIP column of SEGMENT table.

Like

```
SQL> create table t (x int primary key);


SQL> insert into t values(1);

SQL> create table t_c (x int);


SQL> insert into t_c values(1);


SQL> insert into t_c values(2);


SQL> commit;


SQL> alter table t_c add constraint t_c_x foreign key(x)
  2  references t(x);
alter table t_c add constraint t_c_x foreign key(x)
                               *

ORA-02298: cannot validate (SCOTT.T_C_X) - parent key not found 


SQL> select * from t_c where not exists (select *
  2  from t where t.x = t_c.x);

                      X                                                         
-----------------------                                                         
                      2
```

Also Oracle provides the ability to create constraint in NOVALIDATE status, this prevents Oracle from checking data during contraint creation:

```
SQL> alter table t_c add constraint t_c_x foreign key(x)
  2  references t(x) enable novalidate;

Table altered.
```

but this can have undesirable side effects because data in both tables are not consistent.